# Ionic & Angular App with Tabs and SideMenu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I started my first Ionic app with the Tabs template, and I want to add a navbar side menu  that will work on all 6 tabbed pages.

I've spent hours going through a few problems but the problem that I'm having is that it can not find the StatusBar or SplashScreen plug-ins.

I tried a few different methods to get the side menu, but the one I am currently trying has gotten me the furthest. Appreciate any alternative methods as well.

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {NewsfeedService} from './services/newsfeed.service'

import { NewsPage } from '../pages/news/news';
import { PlayersPage } from '../pages/players/players';
import { TeamsPage } from '../pages/teams/teams';

import { TabsPage} from '../pages/tabs/tabs'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [NewsfeedService]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage:any = TabsPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Homepage', component: NewsPage },
      { title: 'Team Research', component: TeamsPage },
      { title: 'Player Research', component: PlayersPage }
    ];

  }
  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();

    });
  }
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
                {{p.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: Can you please re-create the issue in Plnkr? Also, what exact problems do you have with displaying the side menu?